# Where Spark stores intermediate result/partition before shuffle

Tags: caching, apache-spark

Assume I have a clusters with 10 executors. I have a code like following:

```
val tokenized = sc.textFile(args(0)).flatMap(_.split(' ')).map((_, 1))
val wordCounts = tokenized.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

The file is very big --bigger than total mem of the cluster. Saying,I set partition number 100, so each partition is able to be loaded in exec, and I have 100 tasks doing load and flatmap. My question is where is the tokenized rdd/partition(the intermediate result stored) stored, --I did not use `cache()`? I assume spark would spill the partitions into disk. In this case, what is the different btw the code with cache?

```
val tokenized = sc.textFile(args(0)).flatMap(_.split(' ')).map((_, 1)).cache() 
val wordCounts = tokenized.reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Will spark still shuffle even I cached the tokenized rdd?

Answer (score 1):

> I assume spark would spill the partitions into disk.

That's correct. Spark will store data in the local file system if needed.

> what is the different (...) with cache?

Not much. Caching doesn't affect the first execution. It will only try to store data so it can be reused later.

> Will spark still shuffle even I cached the tokenized rdd?

Yes, it will. Caching doesn't replace shuffling although caching can be obsolete here since shuffle automatically caches temporary files.

Comment: Imply from your answer, in above case- terminate after word count , the cache version performances worse than the version without cache. Am I right.

Comment: It is hard to say without a context. Caching will be close to useless if data is not reused. Otherwise behavior can be different depending on Spark version (pre 1.6.0, post 1.6+ with unified memory management).